# Setting up Go environment for creating custom Terraform providers

Tags: go, terraform

I am getting a stuck while trying to create a Terraform provider.  I have been following the advice given on [https://www.terraform.io/docs/extend/writing-custom-providers.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAZGv.png) but when I go to build my binaries via Go `go build -o terraform-provider-example` I get several missing packages errors.

So I then work my way down the list of missing packages and use `go get ...` to get those packages installed in my Go libraries.

I get an error indicating that `github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2` cannot be found.  I navigate to the location and sure enough it doesn't exist.

[Package not available at install time screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAZGv.png)

[Package not available with go get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQnv0.png)

So I am getting stuck and unable to build these providers.  I have looked for a while now trying to find something which describes how to setup the environment for creating providers but have been unsuccessful so far. Can anyone help get me going?

Comment: What's the exact error you get? If you could include the exact command you ran as well then that would also be useful.

Comment: Is this using the new SDK for Terraform providers or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terraform Core and Terraform provider development requires using the Go toolchain in the new "modules mode", which in current versions of Go is not the default.

The easiest way to ensure you're working in modules mode is to clone the repository you want to work on *outside* the `$GOPATH/src` directory. Development outside of `GOPATH` is only supported in Modules mode, and so the Go toolchain assumes that you intend to use modules mode if you are working in that way.

One reason why Terraform development requires modules mode (though not the only one) is that it has a dependency on `github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2`, which is a module path type that is not supported in the old `GOPATH` mode because previously the Go toolchain was only able to install from the `master` branch of a particular remote dependency in a Git repository. The module path `github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2` is the Go Modules way to specify using the second major version of HCL, whereas `github.com/hashicorp/hcl` is the first major version.

In modules mode, it should be sufficient to just run `go build -o terraform-provider-example` (or, if you prefer, `go install`) and it will automatically fetch the dependencies to the local modules cache and use them from there. In modules mode, `go get` is for changing the dependencies recorded in `go.mod` rather than for installing existing dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I am relatively new to Go so I appreciate the clarification.  I placed the sample Terraform code outside of my `GOPATH` and made it a module, `go mod init mymodule/test`.  Then I attempted to build using `go build -o terraform-provider-example` and everything worked nicely.  Thanks again!!

Comment: @martin-atkins I followed this. However, when I `go build -o`, I get following: 
<code>
# runtime
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/stubs_x86.go:10:6: stackcheck redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/stubs_amd64x.go:10:6
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/unaligned1.go:11:6: readUnaligned32 redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/alg.go:321:40
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/unaligned1.go:15:6: readUnaligned64 redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/alg.go:329:40
<code>

Comment: @PrabhasGupte those error messages refer to code from the Go standard library rather than from any Terraform code. I think there's something wrong with your Go installation; perhaps you could ask about it as a new question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks @MartinAtkins indeed those were Go specifics. I had to remove the `pkg` directory and reinstall the golang (to be safer side). Apparently there were some packages brought in by older golang version, mixed with some downloaded by newer.